# Auto-assign metadata when uploading via Document Library View web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document-upload

In Sharepoint Online, I have added Document Library View web parts to most pages.
I have also added a metadata (column) called Page to all Document libraries.

The idea is for the Document Library View to filter the site's documents so it only shows documents belonging to the page.

So far, so good.
The problem is that when uploading a new document, the metadata Page has to be filled in manually by the user.

What is the easiest way to make this happen automatically, across all pages?
Should I create a custom Upload form and assign it to all Document Library View web parts?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a custom Upload form and assign it to all Document Library View web parts, you can create workflow on the document library with "Set field in current item" action.

[image]

Set Page to the value you want.

Choose start workflow automatically when an item is created.

Comment: OK. I am trying to create the workflow on the library. I started with "When a file is created". What is the workflow action called that sets metadata? I can only see "Get file metadata". 
Also, I will need to access the name of the page where the user is uploading.

Comment: I think "Update List Item" is what I am looking for.

Comment: Yes, you can use "Update List Item", but I would suggest you using "Set field in current item" action.

Comment: "Set field in current item" is not available in Flow, only in Sharepoint 2013.

Comment: Flow and SharePoint designer workflow are different.